# How to indent text and make indents

Tags: support, markdown

In [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385525/functional-equations-with-3-variables) I wanted to break the lines to improve readability and indent some of the lines.  The only way I could find to indent the lines was to use \quad  Hitting one return doesn't cause a line break in the displayed text, just in the edit window.  When I hit two returns, I get a double space.  I also tried putting \ in my $\LaTeX$ but as I wasn't in display mode it didn't work.   How do I get single returns and indents?

Comment: I don't see anything like that here in [markdown editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help). I found this question at SO: [How to indent in a few lines in Markdown markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046263/how-to-indent-in-a-few-lines-in-markdown-markup)

Answer (score 6):

The best thing I can think of
    is to end the preceding line with two whitespaces
       (which creates a single line break)
          and copy-paste several `&nbsp;` at the beginning of next line.

(Turns out this is same method as in the link Martin posted.)

Comment: I tried the two spaces.  It works great.

Comment: @RossMillikan Next stage: writing all answers as properly indented haiku.